# Error in randomForest.default(m,y,...) : Can't have empty classes in y

Tags: r, classification, random-forest

I wish to perform classification with respect to 8 different categories using all their features stored in a csv.

I want to use 5 fold cross validation, with ntree being between 25 and 375 (incrementing by 25 each time) and the number of mtry being 2,4,6,8. Here is the code used:

```
# Load the required library
library(randomForest)

# Convert labels to factors
mydata$label <- as.factor(mydata$label)

# Set the range of values for number of trees (Nt) and number of predictors (Np)
nt_values <- seq(25, 375, by = 50)
np_values <- c(2, 4, 6, 8)

# Initialize variables to store the best accuracy and corresponding parameters
best_accuracy <- 0
best_nt <- 0
best_np <- 0

# Perform grid search
for (nt in nt_values) {
  for (np in np_values) {
    # Initialize a vector to store cross-validated accuracies for this combination
    cv_accuracies <- numeric(5)  # 5-fold cross-validation
    
    # Perform cross-validation
    set.seed(123)  # For reproducibility
    folds <- cut(seq(1, nrow(mydata)), breaks = 5, labels = FALSE, stratified = TRUE)  # Use stratified folds
    for (i in 1:5) {
      test_indices <- which(folds == i, arr.ind = TRUE)
      train_data <- mydata[-test_indices, ]
      test_data <- mydata[test_indices, ]
      
      # Train a random forest classifier
      rf_model <- randomForest(label ~ ., data = train_data, ntree = nt, mtry = np)
      
      # Predict on the test set
      predictions <- predict(rf_model, newdata = test_data)
      
      # Calculate accuracy for this fold
      cv_accuracies[i] <- sum(predictions == test_data$label) / nrow(test_data)
    }
    
    # Calculate mean cross-validated accuracy for this combination
    mean_accuracy <- mean(cv_accuracies)
    
    # Update best_accuracy and corresponding parameters if needed
    if (mean_accuracy > best_accuracy) {
      best_accuracy <- mean_accuracy
      best_nt <- nt
      best_np <- np
    }
  }
}
```

The error that occurs is:

```
Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : Can't have empty classes in y.
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: As per the error message, check the `label` variable of your data set. Are there any categories that are not represented in the training data?

Comment: When you do selection across groups, you obviously get some whether the randomness give you empty groups.